# Execute OR and AND conditionals with ActiveRecord helpers

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a database-backed calendar in RoR, and the first step of this is to return all events that fall within a given year. My events table schema is as follows:

```
id:integer description:string startdate:datetime enddate:datetime
```

In English, I think this is the logic I need to execute to return all events that fall within a given year:

> (when **event start** is less than **year start** AND **event end** is greater than **year start**) OR
>
> (when **event start** is greater than **year start** AND **event end** is less than **year end**) OR
>
> (when **event start** is less than **year end** AND **event end** is greater than **year start**)

The first line gets all the events that end in the given year, the second line gets all the events that are within the year and the last line gets all events that start within the year.

**Could this logic be more efficient?**

I've read the ActiveRecord manual and created a fair few dynamic sites, but I've only needed to go `Person.find(34)` or `Person.where(name: 'Jimmy')` and really don't know how to execute the above logic with ActiveRecord's helper methods!

Comment: you can do it in a single query the why you are using combination of three queries. Are you belongs to ruby on rails developer of any other technology ?

Comment: I don't have much practise with SQL statements. I'd be interested to see how it could be done with one query :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a scope in your model

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

    scope :event_in_year, lambda { |year|  where('(events.startdate < ? AND events.enddate > ? ) OR (events.startdate > ? AND events.enddate < ? ) OR (events.startdate < ? AND events.enddate > ? )', year.beginning_of_year, year.beginning_of_year, year.beginning_of_year, year.end_of_year, year.end_of_year, year.beginning_of_year )}
    end
```

and then use this scope to find events between any year , by passing that year to this scope

Comment: Cool, that answers my question, but do you think the query could be simplified?

Comment: off-course yes , check out this http://makandracards.com/makandra/984-test-if-two-date-ranges-overlap-in-ruby-or-rails

Comment: if you think , my answer is correct, would you mind accepting it .

Answer (score 1):

With `ActiveRecord` `where` method, you can pass a `string` query to suit your needs. So something like:

```
your_string = "events.start_date > ...."
Model.where(your_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify to

```
SELECT DISTINCT  id, description FROM calendar
WHERE enddate >= myyear AND endate <= myyear + 1
  OR (startdate >= myyear AND startdate <= myyear + 1)
```

The first WHERE clause line gives all ending in that year including these starting and ending in that year, the second gives all starting in that year. With DISTINCT you get the ending and starting in the same year only once

For the exact syntax the database should be known